# How to get the array index or iteration number with an each iterator?

Tags: ruby, indexing, iterator

I'm iterating through an array in ruby with each. Is there an easy way to get the iteration number or array index without going back to a for loop?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Ah, got it.

```
each_with_index
```

woo!

edit: whoops!

Answer (score 1):

For completeness' sake.

```
Thing.each_with_index {|obj, index_num| puts [obj, index_num].join(" has an index of ")}
```