# Index count method for iterators in ruby?

Tags: ruby

When moving over an iteration such as:

```
array.each do |row|
  puts "Current row count: " + row.current_row_index
  # do some more stuff
end
```

Is there a way to get the index of the current iteration / row?  Obviously I can just throw in a counter, but I'm curious if there's a shortcut for an index function that shows it's current position.

Been digging through the available methods via `pry`, however I've not seen anything that seems to do this out of the box.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the array index or iteration number with an each iterator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/706115/how-to-get-the-array-index-or-iteration-number-with-an-each-iterator)

Comment: Thanks, but the answers below are both a little more verbose and offer additional insight.  Further I think this question is a bit more verbose / explanatory as well.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
array.each_with_index |row, index|
  puts index
end
```

Comment: array.each_with_index do |row, index|
  puts index
end

Answer (score 6):

If you need exactly the index

```
array.each_index do |index|
  puts index
end
```